# Pandas: Find difference in rows with same index in any column

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample dataframe:**

```
In [1898]: df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,0,5,5,6,6,8,8], 'table_name':['f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person'], 'column_name':['active', 'actv', 'ssn', 'ssn', 'pl', '
      ...: pl', 'prefix', 'prefix'], 'data_type':['integer', 'integer', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'integer'], 'default':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'max_length
      ...: ':[np.nan, np.nan, 256, 99, 256, 256, 256, 256]})

In [1899]: df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,0,5,5,6,6,8,8], 'table_name':['f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person', 'f_person'], 'column_name':['active', 'actv', 'ssn', 'ssn', 'pl', '
      ...: pl', 'prefix', 'prefix'], 'data_type':['integer', 'integer', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'bigint', 'varchar', 'integer'], 'default':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'max_length'
      ...: :[np.nan, np.nan, 256, 99, 256, 256, 256, 256]})

In [1900]: df = df.set_index('index')

In [1901]: df
Out[1901]: 
      table_name column_name data_type  default  max_length
index                                                      
0       f_person      active   integer      NaN         NaN
0       f_person        actv   integer      NaN         NaN
5       f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN       256.0
5       f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN        99.0
6       f_person          pl   varchar     10.0       256.0
6       f_person          pl    bigint      NaN       256.0
8       f_person      prefix   varchar      NaN       256.0
8       f_person      prefix   integer      NaN       256.0
```

If you see here, the rows with common index have atleast one difference amongst them.

**For ex:**

Rows with index `0`, have difference in `column_name`.

Rows with index `5`, have difference in `max_length`.

Rows with index `6`, have differences in both `data_type` and `default`.

Rows with index `8`, have difference in `data_type`.

**Expected Output:**

```
[
 {
  0: {'column_name': ['active', 'actv']},
  5: {'max_length': [256, 99]},
  6: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'bigint'], 'default': [10, np.nan]},
  8: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'integer']}
 }
]
```

This is part of a bigger problem. I've kind of solved it till here. Not sure how to proceed further. Any ideas?

Comment: can you have more than 2 rows per index?

Comment: @Ben.T No. Always 2 rows per index.

Comment: Does my solution works for you?

Comment: @jezrael Can you please have a look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution similar like @Riccardo Bucco solution with [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and because always 2 values per groups output is converting to list only:

```
f = lambda x:  {c: x[c].tolist() for c in x.columns if x[c].nunique(dropna=False) != 1}
d = df.groupby('index').apply(f).to_dict()
print (d)

# {0: {'column_name': ['active', 'actv']},
#  5: {'max_length': [256.0, 99.0]}, 
#  6: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'bigint'], 'default': [10.0, nan]}, 
#  8: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'integer']}}
```

Solution with always 2 rows per groups index values:

```
m = df.index.duplicated()
m1 = df.fillna('miss')[m].ne(df.fillna('miss')[~m])

s = (df.where(m1)
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=[0,1])
       .agg(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) == 2 else [*x, np.nan]))
print (s)
index             
0      column_name        [active, actv]
5      max_length          [256.0, 99.0]
6      data_type       [varchar, bigint]
       default               [10.0, nan]
8      data_type      [varchar, integer]
dtype: object

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{0: {'column_name': ['active', 'actv']}, 
 5: {'max_length': [256.0, 99.0]}, 
 6: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'bigint'], 
     'default': [10.0, nan]},
 8: {'data_type': ['varchar', 'integer']}}
```

Comment: Is this the fastest way to solve this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Hmmm, hard question. How many rows is in Dataframe?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - one idea - can you try if working in real data? `df.fillna('miss')[df.index.duplicated()].ne(df.fillna('miss')[~df.index.duplicated()])` ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - added new solution

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the index of `df` and then just run this:

```
output = [(
    df.groupby('index')
      .apply(lambda data: {col: data[col].unique().tolist()
                           for col in data.columns
                           if len(data[col].unique()) > 1})
      .to_dict()
)]
```