# Unique groupnumber to a dateset by true or false

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I was trying for a few days to get my program an step up.

I want to group and count all my groups.

| date | pump | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-06 12:01:00 | false | 0 |
| 2018-01-06 12:01:30 | true | 1 |
| 2018-01-06 12:02:00 | true | 1 |
| 2018-01-06 12:02:30 | false | 0 |
| 2018-01-06 12:03:00 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:03:30 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:04:00 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:04:30 | false | 0 |

with:

```
group = df['pump'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

i get

| date | pump | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-06 12:01:00 | false | 1 |
| 2018-01-06 12:01:30 | true | 1 |
| 2018-01-06 12:02:00 | true | 1 |
| 2018-01-06 12:02:30 | false | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:03:00 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:03:30 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:04:00 | true | 2 |
| 2018-01-06 12:04:30 | false | 3 |

so the last false is always with the true group.

Thanks fot the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups staring by first `True`s group by chain shifted mask by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last set `0` for `False` values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['group1'] = ((df['pump'] & ~df['pump'].shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()
                                                                  .where(df['pump'], 0))
print (df)
                  date   pump  group  group1
0  2018-01-06 12:01:00  False      0       0
1  2018-01-06 12:01:30   True      1       1
2  2018-01-06 12:02:00   True      1       1
3  2018-01-06 12:02:30  False      0       0
4  2018-01-06 12:03:00   True      2       2
5  2018-01-06 12:03:30   True      2       2
6  2018-01-06 12:04:00   True      2       2
7  2018-01-06 12:04:30  False      0       0
```

---

Why is wrong first solution: (seems working in sample)

```
df['group1'] = (~df['pump']).cumsum().where(df['pump'], 0)
print (df)
                  date   pump  group  group1
0  2018-01-06 12:01:00  False      0       0
1  2018-01-06 12:01:30   True      1       1
2  2018-01-06 12:02:00   True      1       1
3  2018-01-06 12:02:30  False      0       0
4  2018-01-06 12:03:00   True      2       2
5  2018-01-06 12:03:30   True      2       2
6  2018-01-06 12:04:00   True      2       2
7  2018-01-06 12:04:30  False      0       0
```

but if change data:

```
df['group1'] = (~df['pump']).cumsum().where(df['pump'], 0)
print (df)
                  date   pump  group  group1
0  2018-01-06 12:01:00  False      0       0
1  2018-01-06 12:01:30  False      0       0 <- changed false
2  2018-01-06 12:02:00   True      1       2 <- starting by 2
3  2018-01-06 12:02:30  False      0       0
4  2018-01-06 12:03:00   True      2       3
5  2018-01-06 12:03:30   True      2       3
6  2018-01-06 12:04:00   True      2       3
7  2018-01-06 12:04:30  False      0       0


df['group1'] = (~df['pump']).cumsum().where(df['pump'], 0)
print (df)
                  date   pump  group  group1
0  2018-01-06 12:01:00   True      1       0 <- changed false, starting true group by 0
1  2018-01-06 12:01:30   True      1       0
2  2018-01-06 12:02:00   True      1       0
3  2018-01-06 12:02:30  False      0       0
4  2018-01-06 12:03:00   True      2       1
5  2018-01-06 12:03:30   True      2       1
6  2018-01-06 12:04:00   True      2       1
7  2018-01-06 12:04:30  False      0       0
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254088/pandas-find-difference-in-rows-with-same-index-in-any-column/71254294#71254294)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was also trying by shift it down, but then I get the Error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. 
The code goes on:
g = df.groupby(group)
df['change'] = g['[TE] Heizkreis 1-Raumtemperatur'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer').cumsum())
df['runtime'] = g['Zeit'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0, downcast='infer').cumsum())

Comment: @Patrik.so - can you try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution for default index?

Comment: I tryed all of these:
df = df.reset_index()
df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

got it:
i set the index in the code above. Now it works. thanks.

Comment: @Patrik.so - What is your pandas version?

Comment: 1.2.4 but now I will update it to 1.4.1

Comment: @Patrik.so - I think it should help